# How can I continuously load the position data from .txt file?

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, load, text-parsing, continuous

In Unity3D, I want to load position data from text file.
Here is an example of the text file.

data_01.txt

1; -5; -10

data_ 02.txt

2; 2; 5

data_03.txt

3; 2; 4

...............

all files are 1 line.

I'd like to input these data into a object.

I want to load text file in 30 text files per 1 second.
There is code saving position data.

```
 public void    Start()

 {
     try
     {
         System.IO.StreamWriter    saveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("savefile.txt", false);
         Transform[]    transforms = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Transform)) as Transform[];
         foreach (Transform t in transforms)
         {
             this.saveFile.WriteLine(t.position);
         }
     }
     catch (System.Exception ex)
     {
         Debug.Log(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
         saveFile.Close();
     }
 }
```

How can I implement code loading position data in Unity continuously?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you want to do that? That sounds pretty inefficient.

Comment: @GunnarB. Yes, very very inefficient. His game mechanics is probably to see how long a computer's SSD  would last. Level 1 is 30 text files per 1 second. Level 2 is 50,000 text files per 1 second.Level 3 is 500,000 text files per 1 second. Each level increments file write amount.

Comment: @GunnarB. Because simulation program give me 1 text data per second....

Comment: Is that from unity or some outside program? Realtime?

Comment: @GunnarB. Yes. I want to visualize my data in realtime. As soon as I get the data, I visualize it in Unity3D.

Comment: Is the simulation program a custom one or some third party stuff? I would have a look if it is possible to create some stream from that program to your unity program and don't save stuff in files. That would be mostly c# related I think.

Comment: The quickest way to do for a prototype is probably to use OSC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write some code where you use System.IO and use that to read the text file. Then you could use Regex to split the string at a semicolon. Here is some example code. The code is written on my iPhone so it may not be perfect.

```
using System.io
using System.Regex
using unityengine;

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file name");

String read = reader.Read();
String[] points = Regex.Split(read,";");
//now you can use the points array to visualize your data
```

You will probably need to put this In a for loop to get all of your files but this should work. Also tell me about any mistakes in my code and I will try to fix them.